# Neither wget nor curl downloads this wikipedia api request

Tags: linux, wget, curl, api

I can perfectly download [this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=revisions&rvprop=content&rvsection=0&titles=wikipedia&format=php) and save it as a text file in a web browser environment. But I can't download and save that wikipedia api request using neither wget nor curl. I use `wget -O file.txt https://that-ugly-url`, but it contains a different html content rather than the correct api reply which I'm able to download using a browser.

Answer (score 1):

Put the link between quotation marks like below. In most of the shells **?,&** have special meanings.

```
wget -O file.txt "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=revisions&rvprop=content&rvsection=0&titles=wikipedia&format=php"
```